# LibGDX renderable only passing through shaders once?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I have a something for 3D sprites that looks something like https://xoppa.github.io/blog/a-simple-card-game/ 's last step. Which generates its renderable like this

```
 public void getRenderables(Array<Renderable> renderables, Pool<Renderable> pool) {
        meshBuilder.begin(mesh.getVertexAttributes());
        meshBuilder.part("cards", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, renderable.meshPart);
        for (Card card : this) {
            meshBuilder.setVertexTransform(card.transform);
            meshBuilder.addMesh(card.vertices, card.indices);
        }
        meshBuilder.end(mesh);

        renderables.add(renderable);
    }
```

The strange part is, it seems that the first time it gets rendered by a modelbatch is the only thing it'll ever look like. For example, if I render it with normal shaders in a framebuffer, then render it again with depthmap shaders (which only output varying shades of gray), it somehow has color. From this, I assume that it just doesn't pass through the shaders again for whatever reason.

Does anyone know why this is? It seems so bizarre to me.

And while I do know that decals exist, I want the "3D sprites" to be rendered along with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it working. The issue is that it only adds the renderable once; instead, it needs to add a new renderable each time.

```
val renderable = pool.obtain()
renderable.material = mat
...
renderables.add(renderable)
```

edit:

Better answer, renderables cache the shader they use. renderable.shader = null will do the trick as well.